# How to bin timestamp data into buckets of n minutes in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query which works, binning timestamped "observations" into buckets whose boundaries are defined by the bins table:

```
SELECT
  count(id),
  width_bucket(
      time :: TIMESTAMP,
      (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT start_time
                    FROM bins
                    WHERE owner_id = 'some id'
                    ORDER BY start_time ASC) :: TIMESTAMP[])
  ) bucket
FROM observations
WHERE owner_id = 'some id'
GROUP BY bucket
ORDER BY bucket;
```

I would like to modify this to allow for querying arbitrary n-minute bins starting from a specified timestamp, rather than having to pull from from an actual "bins" table.

That is, given a start time, a "bin width" in minutes, and a number of bins, is there a way I can generate the array of timestamps to pass into the `width_bucket` function?

Alternatively, is there a different/simpler approach to get the same results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function [`generate_series(start, stop, step interval)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html), e.g.

```
select array(
    select generate_series(
        timestamp '2018-04-15 00:00', 
        '2018-04-15 01:00', 
        '30 minutes'))

                               array                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"2018-04-15 00:00:00","2018-04-15 00:30:00","2018-04-15 01:00:00"}
(1 row)
```

Example in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=21e2a8d357ebc84d990276d3ea64ea33)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @klin I've tried to implement this but frankly got nowhere close. It would greatly help if there was a reproducible solution. I've made an R+Postgres script that works for numeric field binning but not datetime https://gist.github.com/geotheory/7449a5b08392200300e58fab10732706  Would it be possible to adapt the SQL to show how your method could be applied?  This would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Awesome thanks @klin. How would you return the timestamp breaks in the response, or are you suggesting to call that seperately and joining the two outside postgres?

Comment: @geotheory - You can do that in Postgres, see [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9dc4c219b2a061aea97d33566dfcc749) It may be simpler in an application though.

Answer (score 5):

The above answers seem to do what you want, but as of PostgreSQL 14, there is now a function [date_bin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) just for binning timestamps.

Quoting the documentation:

> `date_bin(`***`stride`***`,`***`source`***`,`***`origin`***`)`
>
> ***`source`*** is a value expression of type `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone`. (Values of type `date` are cast automatically to `timestamp`.) ***`stride`*** is a value expression of type `interval`. The return value is likewise of type `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone`, and it marks the beginning of the bin into which the ***`source`*** is placed.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> SELECT date_bin('15 minutes', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-11 15:44:17', TIMESTAMP > '2001-01-01');
> Result: 2020-02-11 15:30:00
>
> SELECT date_bin('15 minutes', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-11 15:44:17', TIMESTAMP '2001-01-01 00:02:30');
> Result: 2020-02-11 15:32:30
> ```
>
> In the case of full units (1 minute, 1 hour, etc.), it gives the same result as the analogous `date_trunc` call, but the difference is that `date_bin` can truncate to an arbitrary interval.
>
> The ***`stride`*** interval must be greater than zero and cannot contain units of month or larger.

I would like to call special attention to the line

> The return value [...] marks the **beginning of the bin into which the source is placed**.

This means that input timestamps will always be binned by "rounding down", rather than binning to whichever bin is closest. E.g. if you do:

```sql
SELECT date_bin('1 hour', '2021-10-13 00:59:59', '2021-10-13 00:00:00');
```

Then the result will be `2020-10-13 00:00:00` (rounded down by 59 minutes and 59 seconds), NOT `2021-10-13 01:00:00` (which is only one second away from the supplied timestamp). So the `date_bin` function does something slightly different than exactly what you ask for, but I figure this is good to post for anyone coming here in the future.

Comment: Is there a known reason why `stride` cannot be months or larger? And what happens if I "cheat" by specifying e.g. `365 days`?

Comment: @theberzi The docs don't explicitly say why stride intervals with units of month or greater are forbidden, but I suspect it's because the exact length of units like 'month' or 'year' aren't always the same - February has 28 days, December has 31 days, most years are 365 days but leap years are 366, etc. As for 'cheating' by specifying an interval of `365 days`, it might not work as you expect it to, depending on your intentions. For example, `date_bin('365 days', '2019-01-01', '2018-01-01')` gives `2019-01-01` as is probably expected. ... (cont.)

Comment: @theberzi ... (cont., part 2), And if you do `date_bin('365 days', '2020-01-01', '2018-01-01')`, you get `2020-01-01`, which is also expected. However, if you do `date_bin('365 days', '2021-01-01', '2018-01-01')`, you get `2020-12-31`. This is because 2020 was a leap year, and `date_bin` doesn't care about niceties like that - it just calculates the bins by repeatedly adding the interval to the origin date, and true to its documentation, `2019-01-01` is 365 days after `2018-01-01`, `2020-01-01` is 365 days after that, and `2020-12-31` is 365 days after that.

Comment: Makes sense. That's inconvenient if you want to group by year accounting for leap ones (but it's not my use-case at the moment luckily). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach without a series:

Divide the difference of time and start by the width of the bin (5 minutes in the example) and add 1 because the first bucket of width_bucket(...) is 1 not 0.

```
floor(extract(epoch from (time - '2019-06-04 00:00'::timestamp)) / (5 * 60) ) + 1 as bucket
```

Getting the start of the bin is also possible

```
to_timestamp(floor(extract(epoch from a.time) / (5 * 60)) * (5 * 60)) as bin_start
```

Putting this all together:

```
SELECT
  count(id),
  floor(extract(epoch from (time - '2019-06-04 00:00'::timestamp)) / (5 * 60) ) + 1 as bucket,
  to_timestamp(floor(extract(epoch from time) / (5 * 60)) * (5 * 60)) as bin_start
FROM observations
WHERE owner_id = 'some id'
GROUP BY bucket, bin_start
ORDER BY bucket;
```